# Site sometimes incredibly slow - Apex code execution sleeps for several seconds - any chance to fix?

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, performance

We sometimes experience a very slow response of a Sites page. Usually the page renders in less than a second but sometimes it takes 8 or more seconds.

When digging into the debug logs I recognized that between two lines the execution seems to stop for a couple of seconds. This usually happens not in our APEX code but in the force.com backend directly.

I assume this is a kind of context switch between our org and other orgs.

Is there a way to ensure this context switch will not happen during the execution of specific parts of the code?

here is an example. The backend simply sleeps for 5 seconds.

```
    16:03:15.267 (267157000)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|com__salesforce
16:03:15.267 (267195000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[52]|com.salesforce.api.fast.System.compareObjects(Object, Object)
16:03:15.267 (267211000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[49]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
16:03:15.267 (267226000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[49]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
16:03:15.267 (267253000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[51]|MAP<String,Schema.DescribeFieldResult>.get(Object)
16:03:15.267 (267274000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[51]|MAP<String,Schema.DescribeFieldResult>.get(Object)
16:03:15.267 (267334000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[52]|com.salesforce.api.fast.System.compareObjects(Object, Object)
16:03:15.267 (267341000)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|com__salesforce
16:03:15.267 (267381000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[52]|com.salesforce.api.fast.System.compareObjects(Object, Object)
16:03:20.252 (5252795000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[49]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
16:03:20.252 (5252829000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[49]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
16:03:20.252 (5252873000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[51]|MAP<String,Schema.DescribeFieldResult>.get(Object)
16:03:20.252 (5252902000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[51]|MAP<String,Schema.DescribeFieldResult>.get(Object)
16:03:20.253 (5253018000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[52]|com.salesforce.api.fast.System.compareObjects(Object, Object)
16:03:20.253 (5253027000)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|com__salesforce
```

Comment: Could you post these two lines of debug?

Comment: i added the debug log output.

Comment: @iwerstler what is that managed package? It looks like something native to salesforce but I don't remember ever seeing this in site debug logs. It seems that the comparator method for some of your sobjects is taking a long time to complete. If you compare those sobjects through anonymous apex does it also take a long time?

Comment: that shows up when I raise the system or apex edebug log level to fine/finest (don't remember any more)

Comment: that shows up when I raise the system or apex debug log level to fine/finest (don't remember any more). exactly(!) the same code usually executes without any pausing just 1 out of 50 times it pauses like this.

Comment: I honestly think you should contact SFDC support for this. Intermittent problem, context switching between your org's namespace and the namespace of a managed package, the managed package looks suspiciously like an internal SFDC package...to me, it all amounts to, contact support.

Comment: Are you having large number of concurrent users in your site when you experience this?

Comment: +1 for raising a support case, but honestly I would attribute this to a platform issue that doesn't likely have a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

I'd raise this with support if you have a Developer support agreement as it most likely involves issues far outside your control.

My most likely 'guess' is that its a Java Virtual Machine garbage collection pause which is 'stopping the world'.

I will however cheerfully put that in the category of speculation

http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-tame-java-gc-pauses

"HotSpot’s G1 also has potential but it is prone to same problem as JRockit – sporadically pause time becomes unreasonably long (few seconds). "